# Use of uninitialized value error in perl cgi

Tags: perl, cgi

I am getting the following error when I try to execute my CGI script from the terminal:

```
Use of uninitialized value $friends{"Bob=416-333-6363"} in print at ./new-cgi/data.cgi line 24
```

Here is my script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my %friends;
my $name;
my $phone;

open FILE, "new-cgi/data.dat" or die ("No File\n");

while (<FILE>) {

        chomp;

        ($name, $phone) = split(" ", $_);

        $friends{$name}=$phone;

}

foreach (keys %friends) {

        print "Name:", $_, "\n";
        print "Phone:", $friends{$_}, "\n"; <--This is line 24
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to split on `=`?

Comment: That's what I'm going to tell too

Comment: @tadman I am using split to split name field and phone numbers field.

Comment: It looks like name and phone no is separated by "=" and not space. Try splitting on "="

Comment: Some suggestions for improvement. 1/ `-w` went out of fashion when Perl 5.6 was released in 2000. 1/ Include `$!` in your file open error message (`open ... or die $!`). 3/ Use 3-arg open and lexical filehandles - `open my $file_h, '<', 'new-cgi/data.dat' or die $!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to see without seeing your `new-cgi/data.dat` file, but I assume that the data format is a bunch of lines like "Bob=416-333-6363" in which case you want to split on `/=/` not `" "`.

What's happening now is that you're splitting on a non-existant whitespace so `$name` (the eventual `key`) gets the entire line and `$phone` the eventual `value`, gets an `undef` value. So when you iterate over the hash later, you have a hash with lots of keys (albeit with odd data for the keys) and `undef` values.